# Disconnect all existing connections on API Gateway WebSockets

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

We need an emergency script that will disconnect all users currently connected to our AWS API Gateway WebSockets service. I know that there's a way to [disconnect individual users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-how-to-call-websocket-api-connections.html), but how do we easily disconnect everyone?